# Prove: $F[t]/H[t]$ is isomorphic to $(F/H)[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

- Let $F$    a commutative and unitary ring, and also $F$
  is an integral domain.
- Let $H$ be a proper ideal of $F$.

I want to prove: $F[t]/H[t]$ is isomorphic to $(F/H)[t]$

So my idea is to use the First Isomorphism theorem  with

$$f:F[t]\to (F/H)[t]$$
$$f\left(\sum_{i=0}^n p_it^i\right)\to \sum_{i=0}^n[p_i]t^i$$

So first I must prove that $f$ is an homomorphism so

(1) $f(0_{F[t]/H[t]})=0_{(F/H)[t]}$ [Obvious]

(2) $f(P+Q)=f(P)\bigoplus f(Q)$  [I prove it]

(3) $f(PQ)=f(P)*f(Q)$ : [ I prove it]

To prove $f$ is onto (surjective) is correct just to say if
$$P=\sum_{i=0}^n[p_i]t^i\in(F/H)[t]$$

Then for
$$Q=\sum_{i=0}^np_it^i\in F[t]$$
$$f(Q)=P$$

I feel I don't prove nothing  ...

Comment: Yes, it's the right direction. Just open up the brackets and use that $F\to F/H$ is a ring homomorphism, so that $[p_iq_j]=[p_i][q_j]$.

Comment: @Berci thank you so much, I think I got it